# socketio expressjs difference between two implementation

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Is there any difference between this implementation:

```
   this.app = express();
   this.httpServer = http.createServer(this.app);
   this.io = socket.listen(this.httpServer);
```

And this one:

```
    this.app = express();
    this.server = http.createServer(this.app);
    this.io = socket(this.server);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nopers, the second is a shorthand. :)

The first is provided in the event that you want to import/export the function from your express architecture

It seems like your other question was posted after this, is this still relevant?

Ok let's see what I've done that worked. I have seperated my sockets into a config file because my app.js was getting cluttered.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/')));

  var clients = {};

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io  = require('socket.io')(server);

require('./config/app.socket.js')(io);
server.listen(8001);
io.set("origins", "*:*");
```

So, I cut out the middleman and pass the server directly to the socket.io import. then, I pass the reference to that io server to my app.socket.js file and listen to the server on port 8001

Here is my app.socket.js initialization

```
module.exports = function(io){
  var clients = {};

   var sockets;

  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  sockets = socket;

  socket.on(//your socket function)

}
```